# Matrix where each element is an inner product with the same vector. What is a compact notation of such a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

A matrix is defined as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
 {\bf a}^T{\bf b}_{1,1}, \ldots, {\bf a}^T{\bf b}_{1,N} \\
 \cdots, \cdots, \cdots, \\ 
 {\bf a}^T{\bf b}_{N,1}, \ldots, {\bf a}^T{\bf b}_{N,N}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}_{i,j}$ are $N \times 1$ vector. This is a matrix where each element is an inner product with the same vector. What is a compact notation (that is not element-wise) of such a matrix?

As clarified in the comments, I am looking for a matrix formulation where the vector ${\bf a}$ comes out and is not element-wise notation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see what you are saying. This is indeed a nice element-wise notation. However, I was wondering whether there is a matrix form of A based on a and a bigger B matrix with b{i,j} as its elements. I will edit the question.

Comment: It's $(I_N\otimes a^T)B$.

Comment: I love you. I had a feeling I had to go to Kronecker Products. Please post it as answer so that I can mark it as solved.

Comment: The $(i,j)$th element is not so ugly to write, if you collect all the $b$s into a 3-tensor $b_{ijk}$ then the matrix you're after has elements $\sum_k a_k b_{ijk}$. If this is in a context where the Einstein summation convention makes sense, then its just $ a_k b_{ijk}$

Comment: Thank you. I suppose using tensors might be more practical if I want to do calculus on it following tensor calculus. Thank you for your clarification.